# How to convert a symbol - " † " to HTML code?

Tags: c#, symbols, html-encode

I'm trying to write the dagger '†' symbol to a HTML page which gets converted to a PDF document, but this appears on the PDF as 'â€'

I understand that I need to use the HTML code for this symbol, which is `&#8224;`.

I've done this successfully for the '€' but in these cases I've written the code directly into the HTML. In this case, I'm reading the symbol from an XML file. When I inspect the value of the variable that contains the symbol, it appears as '†'.

I should note that I've tried reading the symbol & the code from the XML file, as follows:

```
<fund id="777" countryid="N0" append="&#8224;" />
```

and

```
<fund id="777" countryid="N0" append="†" />
```

but both are stored in the variable as the symbol, and when I write them to the page, both are rendered as 'â€'. Also, I've tried the following:

```
string code = "&#8224;";
string symbol = "†";
string htmlEncodedCode = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(code);
string htmlEncodedSymbol = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(symbol);

tc.Text = fund.Name + code + " " + symbol + " " + 
    htmlEncodedCode + " " + htmlEncodedSymbol;
```

but only the first works. It appears in the document as:

```
FundName† â€ &#8224; â€
```

Can somebody suggest how I can get this to work?

**Update:**

@James Curran's answer below was correct. Just for the sake of clarity, I had to change the XML to:

```
<fund id="777" countryid="N0" append="&amp;dagger;" />
```

and in my C#:

```
tc.Text = fund.Name + append;
```

Comment: ...Use the version that works?

Comment: @Jason, the version that works is the one that's hard-coded into the C#. That's not an option.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That symbol is generally known as a "dagger" and is represented in html by the entity:
`&dagger;` †

Comment: storing this in the XML file as  
`<fund id="777" countryid="N0" append="&dagger;" />`
returns the error:  
`Reference to undeclared entity 'dagger'.` .. do I need to refer to it differently in the XML?

Comment: @DaveDev: Unfortunately, XML doesn't understand the same named entities as HTML does.  However, you could in theory return it as `&amp;dagger`, which would (hopefully) work.

Answer (score 1):

This is an encoding issue. â€ is probably the Latin-1 representation of the dagger in UTF-8. Try converting the dagger from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Or try to get the PDF to render using UTF-8.

Comment: Indeed. And read Joel Spolsky's "The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)": http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html Really!

Comment: @R. Bemrose it's more likely an HTML issue.  The default encoding for HTTP content is ISO-8859-1.  So if the encoding for the HTML page is not set to UTF-8, that is what the PDF renderer will use.

Answer (score 0):

With the XML file what you probably want to do is something along the lines of:

```
<fund id="777" countryid="N0" append="&amp;#8224;" />
```

The reason is that the XML file will interpret the `&amp;` as the & symbol and the rest as literal text. Thus in your html you will get `&#8224;` and that should do you.